# app-icon of no-gui-app bounces a few minutes in the dock

Tags: c, macos

I’m about to deploy an application without a GUI or console-output. It works flawless but the application icon bounces for like 5 minutes after launching in the dock.

I want to keep the dock-icon (so no LSUIElement=1) but get rid of the bouncing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you your application to appear in the Dock, it will need to have a Cocoa event loop and some amount of GUI (I believe it'll need at a menu bar, at a minimum, and should be able to at least handle a quit event).

Depending on what your application is and how it works, this may or may not be feasible. You'll have to provide more information for us to provide more specific advice.

Comment: I created a Cocoa-application and integrated my C-application within it. That works however how can I process Cocoa-messages during my own main loop?

Comment: Start your application's main loop in a secondary thread and leave the Cocoa main loop running in the primary thread.